# Chain of Responsibility "Exactly one handler"

Tags: c#, design-patterns

Was reviewing the [article in Wikipedia about chain-of-responsibility](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain-of-responsibility_pattern):

As stated in the link:

> [...] for the chain of responsibility, exactly one of the classes in the chain handles the request.

In the C# example we see the following code in the implementation of the ILogger interface:

```
public void Message(string msg, LogLevel severity)
{
  if ((severity & logMask) != 0) //True only if any of the logMask bits are set in severity
  {
    WriteMessage(msg);
  }
  if (next != null) 
  {
    next.Message(msg, severity); 
  }
}
```

As you can see if a logger matches it doesn't halt the chain. Instead it allows the next handler to be invoked and so on. Thus if we issue a logging request like so:

```
   logger.Message("Foo", LogLevel.All);
```

More than one handlers will be invoked, which in my eyes means that the example given for C# is more like a Decorator pattern (all handlers invoked) instead of a Chain-of-Responsibility (exactly one handler at most). Am I missing something?

Comment: I get what you are saying, and IMO logging is not a great example, because, as you say, you would expect that once handled, the chain would be broken.  With the logging example, there's no guarantee that the same message would only be handled by one handler, which is sort of the point of this pattern.

Comment: Wikipedia sucks for design patterns. There are better online references, e.g. https://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/chain_of_responsibility, which states, "_Multiple handlers could contribute to the handling of each request._"

Comment: @Neil would you be kind enough to turn your comment into an answer so that I can mark it and give you proper credit? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IMO logging is not a great example for this pattern, because, as you say, you would expect that once handled, the chain would be broken.

With the logging example as shown, there's no guarantee that the same message would only be handled by one handler, which is sort of the point of this pattern.

A better (and real-life) example of COR is the HTTP stack pipeline in dotnet core, which goes through several different handlers, each of which can terminate the request if they see fit (say the headers are invalid, or the authorisation is incorrect, or the binder fails) before ultimately calling the actual controller function to handle the request.

Comment: I am sorry but isn't that the exact same thing (besides differences in functionality of course) than the logger example?

Comment: No, because, whereas the logger example does something then always calls the next item in the chain, the http pipeline will actually stop the chain when there is an error.

Comment: Yeah well in this posted example, nothing is stopping any implementation of not calling the `next` one